# Identify active class from span in accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, content-management-system, accordion

Ok folks,

I am having some issues with producing an accordion menu with Jquery for a CMS I must use. This old CMS assigns the "active" item class in a span tag, and not the a or li ones. I need to be able to set the active tab via the code activating the span tag, and not the li anchor tag like I have already. Heres the example:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#amenu > li > a').click(function(){
            if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
              $('#amenu li ul').slideUp();
              $(this).next().slideToggle();
              $('#amenu li a').removeClass('active');
              $(this).addClass('active');
            }
          });
        });
    </script>
```

Example output from the CMS is below:

```
<ul id="amenu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><li><span class="currentbranch0">
        <a href="">Content</a></span>
        <ul class="multilevel-linkul-0" title="">
            <li><a href="">Content 2</a></li>
            <li><span class="currentbranch1"><a href="">Content 3</a></span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How would I approach tackling this problem would anyone know? I have different combinations but keep breaking the anchor link. 
Also if I set the anchor active class manually on the page the accordion won't expand the children, as I will be using a CMS though this might not be that big a deal.

Any help would be appreciated

Regards

Nick

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `.closest('span')` in places in your code that are referring to the class `active`:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#amenu > li > a').click(function(){
        if ($(this).closest('span').attr('class') != 'active'){
          $('#amenu li ul').slideUp();
          $(this).next().slideToggle();
          $('#amenu li a').closest('span').removeClass('active');
          $(this).closest('span').addClass('active');
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for that :) . The CMS is quite old which is part of the issue. I( have included in my original post above the actual CMS menu output, which may help :)

Comment: Sorry to point out your code fixed certain issues, but some still remain :(

Comment: @yoyo I'm not 100% sure what you're after. From what I can tell in your HTML snippet, the class name isn't actually called active. Can you set up a fiddle with a data set and describe what you want to have happen?

Comment: Hi Plynx, Sorry, the CMS actually uses currentbranch1 to mark the second list item (currentbranch0 being the first list item), "multilevel-linkul-0" is a class applied to the first nested ul. Because of this it's making it hard for me to use JS to do what I want. I managed to solve the span issue for standard css based drop down (to mark highlighted) by adding span stylings for the class to display as block and have width & height both to be 100%. I'll post a fiddle shortly

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EKe2R/2/ JavaScript fiddle here of the span class not working. http://jsfiddle.net/qSszb/1/ here is the working fiddle, but I can't control the active class (I know the class is not called active by the CMS, but i'm using that purely as e.g). It's a pain the CMS specifies a number for the level of the UL, as well as the fact it adds the class to a span tag. Thanks again

Comment: @yoyo if you know the class is at least *partially* named something, you can select it by a partial match selector like `$("span[class*='currentbranch']")` or `$("ul[class*='multilevel-linkul']")`. In combination with `closest()`, e.g. `.closest("span[class*='currentbranch']")` you should be able to select on the active class even if the class name itself changes.

Comment: Hi Plynx, Thanks again :) . I still can't seem to get the accordion functionality to work :( . http://jsfiddle.net/EKe2R/5/ Updated fiddle here. I'm sure it's something simple, it's just my JS knowledge is fairly basic at best so I can't get my head around it. :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15135822/jquery-hide-uls-and-only-expand-once-particular-class-set-bit-like-an-accordion/15136202#15136202 Here is the final solution that worked for me, thanks to all for helping :)